# Genymotion 2.5 doesnt work with the API16/17 PlayServices

Tags: android, testing, emulation, genymotion

a lot of trouble come up this evening when I tried testing my app with genymotion on older Android-APIs.. (Gapps / Play Services installed by drag- & dropping the zip into the emulators window)

Here are some errors:

> Reason: Executing service
>   com.pepperonas.libredrive/com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService
>       Load: 0.24 / 0.1 / 0.04
>       CPU usage from 5073ms to 0ms ago:
>       0.1% 470/system_server: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 10 minor
>       0% 569/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0% kernel
>       0% 1534/com.google.android.apps.maps: 0% user + 0% kernel
>       0.1% TOTAL: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
>       CPU usage from 104ms to 606ms later:
>       1.8% 665/com.android.phone: 0% user + 1.8% kernel / faults: 2 minor
>       0% TOTAL: 0% user + 0% kernel 06-23 02:08:29.707      470-486/system_process D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection
>   established 0xb8a13a80, tid 486 06-23 02:08:32.107
>   470-481/system_process D/Sensors﹕ Client connection accepted (43)
>   06-23 02:08:33.067      470-520/system_process E/Genymotion﹕ Could not
>   open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present' 06-23
>   02:08:33.567      470-661/system_process W/ThrottleService﹕ unable to
>   find stats for iface rmnet0 06-23 02:08:38.068
>   470-520/system_process E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open
>   '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present' 06-23
>   02:08:43.067      470-520/system_process E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open
>   '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present' 06-23
>   02:08:48.067      470-520/system_process E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open
>   '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present' 06-23
>   02:08:53.068      470-520/system_process E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open
>   '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present' 06-23
>   02:08:58.067      470-520/system_process E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open
>   '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present' 06-23
>   02:09:03.067      470-520/system_process E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open
>   '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present' 06-23
>   02:09:04.780     989-2234/com.google.android.gms
>   I/GoogleURLConnFactory﹕ Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
>   06-23 02:09:04.780      470-560/system_process D/SyncManager﹕ failed
>   sync operation martinpaush@gmail.com u0 (com.google), subscribedfeeds,
>   LOCAL, earliestRunTime 89277, SyncResult: stats [ numIoExceptions: 1]
>   06-23 02:09:06.895      989-994/com.google.android.gms D/dalvikvm﹕
>   GC_CONCURRENT freed 517K, 5% free 10637K/11180K, paused 1ms+1ms, total
>   6ms 06-23 02:09:06.899     770-1365/com.google.process.gapps
>   I/GLSUser﹕ [GLSUser] getTokenFromCache: [account: ,
>   callingPkg: com.google.android.gms, service:
>   oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ads_measurement] 06-23
>   02:09:06.899     770-1365/com.google.process.gapps I/Auth.Core﹕
>   [TokenCache] Missing snowballing token: no granted scopes set. 06-23
>   02:09:06.899     770-1365/com.google.process.gapps I/GLSUser﹕
>   [GLSUser] getTokenFromGoogle [account: , callingPkg:
>   com.google.android.gms, service:
>   oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ads_measurement 06-23
>   02:09:06.939      770-779/com.google.process.gapps D/dalvikvm﹕
>   GC_CONCURRENT freed 357K, 4% free 9747K/10132K, paused 2ms+0ms, total
>   5ms 06-23 02:09:07.003     770-1365/com.google.process.gapps
>   I/GLSUser﹕ [GLSUser] getAuthtoken(,
>   oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ads_measurement) -> status:
>   null) 06-23 02:09:07.003     770-1365/com.google.process.gapps
>   I/GLSUser﹕ [GLSUser] Extracting token using key: Auth 06-23
>   02:09:07.019     770-1365/com.google.process.gapps W/GLSUser﹕
>   [GLSUser] Permission for com.google.android.gms to access
>   oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ads_measurement will be managed
>   locally. 06-23 02:09:07.027     989-2235/com.google.android.gms
>   D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads-1840532237.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
>   06-23 02:09:07.039    2237-2237/? D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: load 0ms,
>   verify+opt 1ms, 182196 bytes 06-23 02:09:07.039
>   989-2235/com.google.android.gms D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- END
>   'ads-1840532237.jar' (success) --- 06-23 02:09:07.039
>   989-2235/com.google.android.gms D/dalvikvm﹕ DEX prep
>   '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/cache/ads-1840532237.jar': unzip in
>   0ms, rewrite 9ms 06-23 02:09:07.387
>   989-994/com.google.android.gms D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 581K,
>   6% free 10643K/11268K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 4ms 06-23 02:09:08.067
>   470-520/system_process E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open
>   '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present' 06-23
>   02:09:13.067      470-520/system_process E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open
>   '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present' 06-23
>   02:09:17.443      470-486/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force
>   finishing activity com.pepperonas.libredrive/.activities.MainActivity
>   06-23 02:09:17.463      385-391/? W/genymotion_audio﹕ out_write()
>   limiting sleep time 44149 to 23219 06-23 02:09:17.483
>   470-486/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1337K, 20% free
>   14363K/17784K, paused 9ms, total 10ms 06-23 02:09:17.483
>   385-391/? W/genymotion_audio﹕ out_write() limiting sleep time 55759 to
>   23219 06-23 02:09:17.487      470-486/system_process
>   I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing ProcessRecord{536d67c8
>   2151:com.pepperonas.libredrive/u0a10071}: user's request 06-23
>   02:09:17.487      470-483/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Process
>   com.pepperonas.libredrive (pid 2151) has died. 06-23 02:09:17.487
>   470-483/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Scheduling restart of
>   crashed service
>   com.pepperonas.libredrive/com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService
>   in 136866ms 06-23 02:09:17.499      470-547/system_process I/qtaguid﹕
>   Failed write_ctrl(s 0 10071) res=-1 errno=1 06-23 02:09:17.499
>   470-547/system_process W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger﹕
>   setKernelCountSet(10071, 0) failed with errno -1 06-23 02:09:17.503
>   385-391/? W/genymotion_audio﹕ out_write() limiting sleep time 67369 to
>   23219 06-23 02:09:17.527      681-681/com.android.launcher
>   W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented 06-23 02:09:17.527 
>   470-470/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Window already
>   focused, ignoring focus gain of:
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@536cc358
>   attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@536c06a4 06-23
>   02:09:17.555      385-391/? W/genymotion_audio﹕ out_write() limiting
>   sleep time 68979 to 23219 06-23 02:09:17.579      385-391/?
>   W/genymotion_audio﹕ out_write() limiting sleep time 60589 to 23219
>   06-23 02:09:17.599      385-391/? W/genymotion_audio﹕ out_write()
>   limiting sleep time 52199 to 23219 06-23 02:09:17.619      385-391/?
>   W/genymotion_audio﹕ out_write() limiting sleep time 33809 to 23219
>   06-23 02:09:17.647      385-391/? W/genymotion_audio﹕ out_write()
>   limiting sleep time 25419 to 23219 06-23 02:09:18.067
>   470-520/system_process E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open
>   '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present' 06-23
>   02:09:23.067      470-520/system_process E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open
>   '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present' 06-23
>   02:09:28.067      470-520/system_process E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open
>   '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'

more...

> 06-23 02:08:09.147    2168-2194/com.google.android.gm E/Gmail﹕ Error
>   finding the version of the Email provider.....
>       android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.android.email
>               at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:80)
>               at com.google.android.gm.EmailMigrationService.a(SourceFile:1279)
>               at com.google.android.gm.EmailMigrationService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:219)
>               at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

and another error:

> 06-23 02:08:09.123    2168-2168/com.google.android.gm E/dalvikvm﹕
>   Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from
>   method com.google.android.gms.common.e.a

I've never seen these errors before.
The same "setup" was running a few hours before totally perfect (the issues came up when I started the updated emulator). Does anybody know how to fix this? I restarted my computer, adb and VirtualBox, but it didn't changed anything.

I'm very sure that the apk is fine and the Maps-Api / AdMob / Analytics is referenced correctly, the same app runs on my real device (HTC m8) without any issues.

Comment: I had this problem, my solution: use AVD and install and Android Virtual Machine with  Google Api and x86 processor with hosted GPU, is same performance that Genymotion.

Comment: I guess it found the issue, see my answer above (for me the x86 is not running on the "original" AVD :-/ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now I got managed the issue. After I flashed [gapps-jb-20130301-signed.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_BZb0NknOIcUWsxcFIzclMyc00/view?usp=sharing) the emulator executes the app without any errors.
This solutions assumes you use:

- Genymotion 2.5
- Virtual device running **API17** (JellyBean)

Hope it helps others. 
Regards